# How to disable phonegap autoreload (At least during dev)

Tags: api, cordova, reload

Here is my issue:

I've installed phonegap and phonegap desktop.
http://code.riffzone.net/phonegap-install-msw/

Now, when I'm working on my application (Jquery Mobile), I'm testing it on a browser, but the application is reloading again and again after every 2 seconds and I can't even write something in the form input, reloading to fast..

I don't understand where this is coming from?

Here is the screen shot of my browser and the firebug console where you can see the page reloading over and over (1) and the api_auto_reload in the console (2).

[image]

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was [phonegap desktop beta](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/12/11/phonegap-desktop-app-beta/) (the minimalist server) and not phonegap (command line) which was causing this bug.

If you have the same issue, make sure you are not using it.

Comment: I have this bug and am using the command line with IntellIJ Idea IDE.. Any suggestions besides disabling the autoreload?

Comment: I had the same issue using phpStorm from the same IDE developers, so I guess this is a bug with jetBrains IDEs making it look like files got changed. Thanks for posting the solution.

Answer (score 9):

The reload should be triggered only when some of your source files is changed. For some reason it does detect change on your files constantly. That reason is quite hard to find out without debugging more. You can, though, turn the auto reload off with *--no-autoreload* switch for `phonegap serve` like this

```
phonegap serve --no-autoreload
```

Comment: Yeah thank you, actually it was "phonegap desktop beta" (the minimalist server) and not phonegap (command line) which was causing this bug.

I get rid of it and no problems, should've tried before asking, but never thought it could be the problem.

I guess beta means beta.. ;-)

Edit : Can't vote for best answer, I don't have the reputation.

Comment: @RomainDerie: If you found the solution, you should post it as separate answer and then [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it for future reference. :)